# How to get back one row matching in a many to many relationship Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to get back a user's pet given the users `id` and the pets `id`.

My tables are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE pet_owner (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  phone_number varchar(50) UNIQUE,
  address varchar(255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  breed varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  weight numeric(5, 2),
  date_of_birth date,
  date_of_death date,
  address varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE pet_petowner (
  owner_id int REFERENCES pet_owner,
  pet_id int REFERENCES pet,
  PRIMARY KEY (owner_id, pet_id)
);
```

The query I have is the following...

```
SELECT pet.id as id, pet.first_name as first_name, pet.last_name as last_name
FROM pet_petowner owner_pet
JOIN pet pet on (owner_pet.pet_id = 1)
WHERE owner_pet.owner_id = 1;
```

Problem is that it seems to get the pet even if the user with the specified `id` does not own that pet. I believe I want to return nothing if this is the case.

I am actually executing this query in my express application as follows...

```
exports.getPet = async (req, res) => {
  const query = `SELECT pet.id as id, pet.first_name as first_name, pet.last_name as last_name
                 FROM pet_petowner owner_pet JOIN pet pet on (owner_pet.pet_id = ${req.params.pet_id})
                 WHERE owner_pet.owner_id = ${req.params.owner_id}`;
  const { rows } = await pool.query(query);
  res.status(200).send(rows[0]);
};
```

but obviously, I have the same problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You join all the pets to the pets of owner of pet 1 and then filter by owner ID. It does not seem right. Look into the condition of your JOIN and you'll find how to fix your problem by your self. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The query needs to indicate **how** to join the two tables:

```
SELECT pet.id as id, pet.first_name as first_name, pet.last_name as last_name
FROM pet_petowner owner_pet
JOIN pet pet on (owner_pet.pet_id = pet.id)
WHERE owner_pet.owner_id = 1 AND pet.id = 1;
```

To use the query securely in node.js you **must** escape the parameters or pass them as placeholders. https://www.atdatabases.org does this automatically using the `sql` tag, so that would look like:

```
exports.getPet = async (req, res) => {
  const query = sql`
    SELECT pet.id as id, pet.first_name as first_name, pet.last_name as last_name
    FROM pet_petowner owner_pet
    JOIN pet pet on (owner_pet.pet_id = pet.id)
    WHERE owner_pet.owner_id = ${req.params.owner_id}
    AND pet.id = ${req.params.pet_id}
  `;
  const rows = await pool.query(query);
  res.status(200).send(rows[0]);
};
```

To do it the library you're currently using you would do:

```
exports.getPet = async (req, res) => {
  const query = `
    SELECT pet.id as id, pet.first_name as first_name, pet.last_name as last_name
    FROM pet_petowner owner_pet
    JOIN pet pet on (owner_pet.pet_id = pet.id)
    WHERE owner_pet.owner_id = $1
    AND pet.id = $2
  `;
  const rows = await pool.query(query, [
    req.params.owner_id,
    req.params.pet_id,
  ]);
  res.status(200).send(rows[0]);
};
```